# Unexpected result of verilog dflipflop code

Tags: verilog

For below verilog dff example output is shown at last(only shown first two lines). I am not able to understand why the always block is executing at time zero whereas I have written always@(posedge clk). posedge clk is not happening at time zero. Can you help me to understand the output?

```
module main;
reg d,clk;
wire q;

always #5 clk++;
always #10 d++;

dff dff(d,clk,q);  

initial 
begin
d = 1;
clk = 1;
$monitor("time = %d d = %d clk = %d q = %d",$time,d,clk,q);
#50 $finish ;
end
endmodule

module dff(input wire d,clk, output reg q);
always @(posedge clk)
begin
q = d;
$display("time = %d inside module dff",$time);
end
endmodule

Output is
time =                    0 inside module dff
time =                    0 d = 1 clk = 1 q = 1
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **non-blocking assignments** (`q<=d;`) while coding **sequential** logic. The non-blocking assignments will assign the LHS in NBA region and we can observe a clock delay between the LHS and RHS.

Refer to [this paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf) for more information on non-blocking assignments usage.

As far as `always` block executing at time-0, there is a `clk` **transition from `x` to `1` at time-0** (from `initial` block). As a result, the simulator counts it as a positive edge. Note that the default value of `reg` is `x`.

We can make different types of clock generators in Verilog/SV as per requirement. Refer to [Cummings paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2006Boston_SystemVerilog_Events.pdf) for examples on different types of clock generators.

Comment: Even if I use non blocking assignment I am getting same output. In my simulator default value of reg is x.  Is it valid to consider x -> 1 transition as posedge?

Comment: You can discus to agree or disagree if it is valid, but it is the standard behavior.

Comment: @Ranju, make `clk=0;` in `initial` block to avoid time-0 event. Moreover, from Verilog/SV standards, a `posedge` shall be detected on the **transition from 0 to x, z, or 1, and from x or z to 1**.